# Basic Queue Optimizations

Tags: optimization, queue

How would one optimize a queue for the typical:

access / store

memory usage

i'm not sure of anyway to reduce memory besides trying to run a compression algorithm on it, but that would take quite a deal of store time as a tradeoff - one would have to recompress everything I think.

As such I'm thinking the typical linked list with pointers.... a circle queue?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: regardless of what is above; how does one make the fastest/least memory intensive basic queue structure essentially?

Answer (score 1):

Linked lists are actually not very typical (except in functional languages or when newbies mistakenly think that a linked list is faster than a dynamic array). A dynamic circular buffer is more typical. The growing (and, optionally, shrinking) works slightly differently than in a dynamic array: if the "data holding part" crosses the end of the array, the data should be copied to the new space in such a way that it remains contiguous (simply extending the array would create a gap in the middle of the data).

As usual, it has some advantages and some drawbacks.

Drawbacks:

- slightly more complicated implementation
- not suitable for lock-free synchronization

Advantages:

- more compact: in the worst case (when it just grew or is just about to shrink but hasn't yet) it has a space overhead of about 100%, a singly linked list almost *always* has an overhead of 100% *or more* (unless the data elements are larger than a pointer) and a doubly linked list is even worse.
- cache efficient: reading happens close to previous reading, writing happens close to previous writing. So cache misses are rare, and when they do occur, they read data that is mostly relevant (or in the case of writing: they get a cache line that will probably be written to again soon). In a linked list, locality is poor and about half of every cache miss is wasted on the overhead (pointers to other nodes).

Usually these advantages outweigh the drawbacks.